# prove that for any $k$-regular graph $G$, $\chi(G) \geq \frac n{n-k}$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

This question is a part of another question that has two sections. In the first section I proved that for any graph $G$, $\frac n{\alpha(G)} \leq \chi(G)$ and $\chi(G) \leq n-\alpha(G)+1$.

Now I don't know how to prove that for any $k$-regular graph $G$, $\chi(G) \geq \frac n{n-k}.$

Note: $\chi(G)$ is the vertex chromatic number of $G$ and $\alpha(G)$ is the independence number of $G$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First an observation.  Let $G$ be some graph colored with $\chi$ colors.
Then one color class must have at least $n/\chi$ vertices.

Now say that $G$ is $k$-regular.
Suppose that $\chi(G) < n/(n - k)$.
One color class must then have at least $n/\chi(G) > n/(n/(n - k)) = n - k$ vertices.

Can you finish the rest ?

Answer (score 1):

Each vertex has a different colour from its $k$ neighbours, so at most $n-k$ vertices can have the same colour.

$\chi(G)$ colours are needed, so $(n-k)\chi(G)\geq n$, so $\chi(G) \geq \frac{n}{n-k}$.

$\square$